# Check if Juniper VPN tunnel is active

Tags: bash, vpn

I'm using Juniper Networks Network Connect to establish a VPN connection. I want to check via the terminal whether this connection is up and running. I can see whether it's up and running or not using `ifconfig` but how would I be able to use a command that actually returns a value that I can feed into another conditional statement?

Comment: I'd say, `grep` is your friend...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `grep`, you can do the following:

`/sbin/ifconfig tun0|grep -ci 'UP'`

to check if your tunnel is running or not.

Thanks @cmaster!